# Insert atomic content into CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Is it possible to insert "atomic" block content into CKEditor?

For example I want to insert `<h1>Test</h1>` just after "B" in `<p>A B C</p>`. Currently with `CKEDITOR.currentInstance.insertHtml('<h1>Test</h1>')`, the block tag is removed and it becomes `<p>A BTest C</p>` (cursor it just after "B"). I want it to be inserted at the end of the P block where the cursor is, like `<p>A B C</p><h1>Test</h1>`

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/T49Pf/3/. When the caret is anywhere in the first paragraph and I click "Insert", I don't have the `h1` tag inserted. But when the caret is in the second (empty) paragraph, I do have the `h1` block element. Now I'd like when I click "Insert" anywhere, the content is inserted in a place that keep it atomic (don't lost the `h1` tag). It is similar to the "magic line" plugin.

Comment: Which version of CKEDITOR are you using?

Comment: [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)

Comment: It's the latest version of CKEditor: 4.2.0. I've just added a live example. It is not ACF because I do have atomic content when the caret is in an empty paragraph (I also choose standard toolbar to have the H1 enabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using [`editor.insertHtml`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) method. This method's behaviour was designed to work with pasted code and your case is most often means that single line or part of it was copied so it should be handled as a text - not as a format.

In your case I'd recommend the [`editor.insertElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertElement) method which is for different purposes (like e.g. image insertion) so it will preserve your element.

Sample from documentation:

```
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<img src="hello.png" border="0" title="Hello" />' );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertElement( element );
```

Comment: Yes it is editor.insertHtml. It was a typo in the question, but the code at jsfiddle is correct. I'll test with insertElement.

Comment: Not really answers the question (insert at the end of the current block element), but it is what I was trying to do. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/T49Pf/4/. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't noticed that additional requirement. You can modify the selection so it is placed where you want and then insert.

Answer (score 0):

header tags (h1-6) are block level elements which cannot be nested inside a `<p>` tag...

Comment: But I like to insert it *after* the P tag instead of stripping it.